# Web Socket issue In clustering Environment

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have configure web socket in my project. IN UAT environment I have two apache server and two web server up to share the load balancing.

Problem is my websocket url get registered with one of the server. Now when ever I'm sending any notification. Notification request doesn't recognize which server it needs to route.

So I'm seeing an intermittent issue of web socket. some times its working most of time it's failing.

I have tested with clustering and sticky session also.

No success so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a backplane to communicate those servers.

Take a look on how SignalR manages to forward messages to all servers: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Then if you want to do something more advanced, take a look to a messaging infrastructure : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30188677/307976